# mocking a service function inside controller using Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine.

my service file contains a function to make a http get method call

```
app.service('myService', ['$http', function($http) {
var incCount = function(total){
        return total++;
    }

    var sampFunction = function(link){

    var promise = $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : link
    }).success(function(data) {        
        promise = data;
        return data;
    });    
    return promise; 

    }

    return {
        incCount: incCount,
        sampFunction : sampFunction 
    };

}]);
```

my controller has function which calls sampFunction in service

```
var url = ....(some url)
myService.sampFunction(url).then(function(res){        
    $scope.data = res[0].myData;
}
```

can anyone help me, on how to mock this service's function call inside the spec for controller?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock JQuery with Jasmine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742435/how-to-mock-jquery-with-jasmine)

Comment: @JasonD: That question is totally different. This question is related to mocking a service which has a http call.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
describe('myService', function () {

    var $httpBackend, myService;

    beforeEach(module("your-module-name"));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _myService_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        myService = _myService_;
    }));

    it("can be instantiated", function () {
        expect(myService).toBeDefined();
    });

    it("should fire GET call to link url", function () {
        var link = "/some-url";
        $httpBackend.expectGET(link).respond({});
        myService.sampFunction(link);
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    });
});
```